# Understanding signed numbers and complements in java

Tags: java, byte, bit, sign, complement

I have a 3 byte signed number that I need to determine the value of in Java.  I believe it is signed with one's complement but I'm not 100% sure (I haven't studied this stuff in more than 10 years and the documentation of my problem isn't super clear).  I think the problem I'm having is Java does everything in two's complement.  I have a specific example to show:

- The original 3-byte number: `0xEE1B17`
- Parsed as an integer (`Integer.parseInt(s, 16)`) this becomes: 15604503
- If I do a simple bit flip (`~`) of this I get (I think) a two's complement representation: -15604504
- But the value I should be getting is: -1172713

What I think is happening is I'm getting the two's complement of the entire int and not just the 3 bytes of the int, but I don't know how to fix this.

What I have been able to do is convert the integer to a binary string (`Integer.toBinaryString()`) and then manually "flip" all of the 0s to 1s and vice-versa.  When then parsing this integer (`Integer.parseInt(s, 16)`) I get 1172712 which is very close.  In all of the other examples I need to always add 1 to the result to get the answer.

Can anyone diagnose what type of signed number encoding is being used here and if there is a solution other than manually flipping every character of a string?  I feel like there must be a much more elegant way to do this.

EDIT: All of the responders have helped in different ways, but my general question was how to flip a 3-byte number and @louis-wasserman answered this and answered first so I'm marking him as the solution.  Thanks to everyone for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to flip the low three bytes of a Java int, then you just do `^ 0x00FFFFFF`.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I knew it would be simple. Your answer is what I was looking for so I'll mark it as the solution, but any idea why I have to add a 1 to that number to get the desired result?

Comment: In two's complement, `~x == -x - 1`.  So that's probably an artifact of the one's complement stuff.

Answer (score 1):

`0xFFEE1B17` is -`1172713`
You must only add the leading byte. `FF` if the highest bit of the 3-byte value is set and `00` otherwise.

A method which converts your 3-byte value to a proper `int`could look like this:

```
if(byte3val>7FFFFF)
  return byte3val| 0xFF000000;
else 
  return byte3val;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response ... when you say "0xFFEE1B17 is -1172713" in what number's complement do you mean?

Comment: @rjcarr: the in nearly all systems (and also by java) used [2-compliment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement)

Answer (score 0):

Negative signed numbers are defined so that `a + (-a) = 0`. So it means that all bits are flipped and then `1` added. See [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Two.27s_complement). You can check that the condition is satisfied by this process by thinking what happens when you add `a + ~a + 1`.

You can recognize that a number is negative by its most significant bit. So if you need to convert a signed 3-byte number into a 4-byte number, you can do it by checking the bit and if it's set, set also the bits of the fourth byte:

```
if ((a & 0x800000) != 0)
    a = a | 0xff000000;
```

You can do it also in a single expression, which will most likely perform  better, because there is no branching in the computation (branching doesn't play well with [pipelining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipeline) in current CPUs):

```
a = (0xfffffe << a) >> a;
```

Here `<<` and `>>` perform byte shifts. First we shift the number 8 bits to the right (so now it occupies the 3 "upper" bytes instead of the 3 "lower" ones), and then shift it back. The trick is that `>>` is so-called [Arithmetic shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift) also known as *signed shift*. copies the most significant bit to all bits that are made vacant by the operation. This is exactly to keep the sign of the number. Indeed:

```
(0x1ffffe << 8) >> 8        ->  2097150
(0xfffffe << 8) >> 8        ->  -2
```

Just note that java also has a unsigned right shift operator `>>>`. For more information, see Java Tutorial: [Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html).

Comment: @MrSmith42 Thanks for pointing that out, I've corrected it. Of course it should be bitwise and/or.